# Installing yarn, npm and Node.js on CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2 image causing issue

Tags: node.js, npm, centos7, yarnpkg

I have to build the Node.js code on CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud.qcow2 image. I'm trying to install node12, yarn1.22 on that image, but not getting any success. Node10 and yarn1.22 work fine. But we need node12 because during development node 12 is used. Getting below error for node12 and yarn 1.22.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
buffer.js:607
slice: (buf, start, end) => buf.utf8Slice(start, end),
                                ^
RangeError: Index out of range
at Object.slice (buffer.js:607:37)
at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:804:14)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:408:41)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1219:22)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
```